# Variable wont work when made in IF batch program

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, batch, batch-file, gaming

I am trying to make a game, and whenever I try it, it says there is a syntax error when it is right

```
:Q3

echo ====================================
echo Do you want to be skilled in:
echo.
echo Speed (1)
echo Enchanting (2)
echo Pickpocket (3)
echo Attack (4)
echo Magic (5)
echo.
echo Say the Number it's labeled as. (1-5)
echo.
echo =====================================

set /p QU3= %NAME%\

if %QU3%== 1 SET SPEE= 1
if %QU3%== 2 set ECH= 1
if %QU3%== 3 set PIC= 1
if %QU3%== 4 set 
if %QU3%== 5 

pause
goto Q4
```

Plz help me as soon as posible!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but try this:

```
@echo off
:Q3

echo ====================================
echo Do you want to be skilled in:
echo.
echo Speed (1)
echo Enchanting (2)
echo Pickpocket (3)
echo Attack (4)
echo Magic (5)
echo.
echo Say the Number it's labeled as. (1-5)
echo.
echo =====================================

SET /P QU3="INPUT:"

if "%QU3%"==1 (SET SPEE=1)
if "%QU3%"==2 (SET ECH=1)
if "%QU3%"==3 (SET PIC=1)
REM if "%QU3%"== 4 set 
REM if "%QU3%"== 5 

echo %QU3% was selected
pause
```

I recommend you to read this tutorial to learn more about batch file syntax: http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/index.html

Comment: I tryed it, and it still did'nt work. but the website was helpful. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the website for a while, i figured it out. this is what i got:
    :Q3

```
echo ====================================
echo Do you want to be skilled in:
echo.
echo Speed (1)
echo Enchanting (2)
echo Attack (3)
echo Magic (4)
echo.
echo Say the Number it's labeled as. (1-5)
echo.
echo =====================================

set SPEE=0
set ENCH=0
set ATTA=0
set MAGI=0

set /p QU3= %NAME%\

if %QU3%== 1 set /a SPEE+=1
if %QU3%== 2 set /a ENCH+=1
if %QU3%== 3 set /a ATTA+=1
if %QU3%== 4 set /a MAGI+=1

pause
```

Comment: **Add the :Q3 to the top of the code**